# Not able to connect to openldap server in ldaps mode - CentOS

Tags: centos, openssl, openldap

I have configured my openldap server in ldaps mode. But after configuring I am not able to connect it on 636 port where as I am able to connect on 389 port

```
[root@testldap certs]# ldapsearch -x -LLL -h testldap.india.airwave.com -p 636 -D  cn=Manager,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com -w  whopee   -b "ou=Users,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com"
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
[root@testldap certs]# ldapsearch -x -LLL -h testldap.india.airwave.com -p 389 -D  cn=Manager,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com -w  whopee   -b "ou=Users,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com"
dn: ou=users,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

dn: cn=Sandeep Lade,ou=users,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com
cn: Sandeep Lade
sn: Lade
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
userPassword:: d2hvcGVl
uid: vlade

dn: cn=Engineering,ou=users,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com
cn: Engineering
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: cn=Sandeep Lade,ou=users,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com
```

Both 389 and 636 are listening

```
[root@testldap certs]# netstat -an | grep 389
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::389                      :::*                        LISTEN
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    19389
[root@testldap certs]# netstat -an | grep 636
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:636                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::636                      :::*                        LISTEN
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     13636
[root@testldap certs]#
```

Able to connect to 636 port using openssl connect

```
[root@localhost sandeeplade]# openssl s_client -connect 10.22.156.157:636 -showcerts -CAfile cacert.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 307 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1516769274
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
[root@localhost sandeeplade]#
```

ldap.conf file

```
[root@testldap certs]# cat /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never


PORT 636
#TLS_CACERTDIR  /etc/openldap/certs
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/certs
TLS_REQCERT allow

ssl start_tls
tls_checkpeer yes
tls_cacertfile /etc/openldap/certs/cacert.pem

[root@testldap certs]#

slapd.conf file

[root@testldap certs]# cat /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
TLSCACertificateFile    /etc/openldap/certs/cacert.pem
TLSCertificateFile      /etc/openldap/certs/server.crt
TLSCertificateKeyFile   /etc/openldap/certs/server.key

# Use the following if client authentication is required
#TLSVerifyClient        demand
# ... or not desired at all
TLSVerifyClient never

[root@testldap certs]#
```

certificates are available in /etc/openldap/certs and they are generated using openssl

```
[root@testldap certs]# cd /etc/openldap/certs/
[root@testldap certs]# ls -lrt
total 96
-r--------. 1 root root    45 Jan 23 21:59 password
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 16384 Jan 23 21:59 secmod.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 65536 Jan 23 21:59 cert8.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 16384 Jan 23 21:59 key3.db
-rw-------. 1 ldap ldap  1743 Jan 23 23:57 server.key.pass
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1094 Jan 23 23:59 server.csr
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4718 Jan 24 00:02 server.crt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1675 Jan 24 00:38 server.key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4537 Jan 24 05:18 cacert.pem
[root@testldap certs]#
```

ldaps enabled in /etc/sysconfig/ldap

```
[root@testldap certs]# cat /etc/sysconfig/ldap
# Options of slapd (see man slapd)
#SLAPD_OPTIONS=

# At least one of SLAPD_LDAP, SLAPD_LDAPI and SLAPD_LDAPS must be set to 'yes'!
#
# Run slapd with -h "... ldap:/// ..."
#   yes/no, default: yes
SLAPD_LDAP=yes

# Run slapd with -h "... ldapi:/// ..."
#   yes/no, default: yes
SLAPD_LDAPI=yes

# Run slapd with -h "... ldaps:/// ..."
#   yes/no, default: no
SLAPD_LDAPS=yes

# Run slapd with -h "... $SLAPD_URLS ..."
# This option could be used instead of previous three ones, but:
# - it doesn't overwrite settings of $SLAPD_LDAP, $SLAPD_LDAPS and $SLAPD_LDAPI options
# - it isn't overwritten by settings of $SLAPD_LDAP, $SLAPD_LDAPS and $SLAPD_LDAPI options
# example: SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:///var/lib/ldap_root/ldapi ldapi:/// ldaps:///"
# default: empty
#SLAPD_URLS=""

# Maximum allowed time to wait for slapd shutdown on 'service ldap stop' (in seconds)
#SLAPD_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT=3

# Parameters to ulimit, use to change system limits for slapd
#SLAPD_ULIMIT_SETTINGS=""
[root@testldap certs]#
```

I am struggling to get the openldap worked from past two days. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your ldpasearch parameters are wrong for an SSL query.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468137/ldapsearch-over-ssl-tls-doesnt-work

You need to use the "-H" iso -h and -p.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .But then even with -H, same error   `[root@testldap ~]# ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldaps://testldap.india.airwave.com:636 -D  cn=Manager,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com -w  whopee   -b "ou=Users,dc=india,dc=airwave,dc=com"
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
[root@testldap ~]#`

Comment: in your test with openssl, you connected to an IP address, not to testldap.india.airwave.com.

Comment: With FQDN also it works `[root@localhost sandeeplade]# openssl s_client -connect testldap.india.airwave.com:636 -showcerts -CAfile cacert.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
139989563025344:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
`

Comment: It does say "error".  Do you consider this "to work"?

Comment: But  its giving  `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` so i believe TLS connection between client and server is OK

Comment: can you add  `-servername testldap.india.airwave.com` to your openssl test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72211/discussion-between-sandeep-lade-and-gerard-h-pille).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to add the server CA root to **/etc/openldap/ldap.conf** :

```
TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt 
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

Also try to run **slapd** with `-d 256` to debug connections And execute ldapsearch with **-d 9**  for debugging also.

I'm sure there is an issue with the generated certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete existing cert cache dirs with pattern like this, if exists:

```
/tmp/openldap-tlsmc-certs--*
```

More info: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/OpenLDAP-and-MozNSS-Compatibility-Layer